# How do I handle AsyncTask incompletion in fragments due to screen rotation

Tags: android

I have an App which opens few fragments (actually 3) through a Fragment container (on Tab) and the first fragment uses AsyncTask to download feeds into the app.
The problem occurs when there is screen rotation - the application crashes.
I temporarily handle this problem by loading the data from PostExecute into private static variable but this problem can still occur when the user first enters the app.

This seems a very common or rampant problem but I've not been able to find outright solution here.
I do understand that this is because of configuration changes due to the screen rotation as the AsyncTask is running on a parallel thread to the UI thread.
I do refrain from using the Java threads/executor/executor service at this stage since there seem a ready-made tool in AsyncTask

I have been unable to interrupt the process in order to restart the activity or the fragment successfully and discard the initial subsequent AsyncTask calls..

In other words, how do I destroy the AsyncTask within a Fragment when there has been continuous configuration changes like Screen Rotation. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MolyListFragment extends Fragment {
public final static String MOLY_ARTICLE_DATA = "No Details";
private static final String TAG = "MOLY";
private static ArrayList<MolyPg> mMolyPgs = null;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (mMolyPgs == null) {
        new MolyLoadTask().execute(getResources().getString(R.string.mly_feed));
    }
    else
        displayMlicles (mMolyPgs); //this displays the arrayList out of static mMolyPgs
}


private class MolyLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MolyPg>> {
@Override
protected ArrayList<MolyPg> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String myUrl = urls[0];
        ArrayList<MolyPg> myMlPgs = null;
    try {
            myMlPgs =  loadXmlFromNetwork(myUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
            getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            getResources().getString(R.string.xml_error);
    }

    return myMlPgs;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MolyPg> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Do some acrobatics here
    }
........    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several solutions you could go with, but they all have one common theme...you shouldn't have long-running operations like that so tightly bound directly to your user interface classes.

If I were to make a suggestion, there are two possibilites that often work well:

- Implement your `AsyncTask` inside of a custom `AsyncTaskLoader` that you can connect to each time your `Fragment` is started up again to retrieve the data or wait for it to come back.  There are a number of callback methods you need to implement, so you'll want to reference the documentation ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)).  You may also want to look at the source for `CursorLoader` to get another example of an `AsyncTaskLoader` implementation.
- Create a "data" `Fragment` in your application whose sole purpose is to manage your background tasks and provide the information when available.  This fragment will have no UI component (i.e. don't override `onCreateView()`) and you will call `setRetainInstance()` so the `FragmentManager` keeps only one around.  When you add the fragment with a constant tag value, all other components in your UI can easily find it via the `FragmentManager` to retrieve the data.  For more information about this, see the docs section [Adding a fragment without a UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding).

Comment: Thanks so much for responding to my plight. I'll go back to drawing board and endeavour to re-write. On thing of note is that my App is dependent on a bi-weekly xml file (non-incremental records) on URL.

I've also been trying to avoid the service-->ContentProvider route but it seems this is inevitable (or is it not?). Is there a way of avoiding the use Service --> contentProvider (SQLHelper?)?.

That is, loading the data from xml in remote URL unto local variable within my fragments and still AVOID the screen-rotation-prone fatal error situation. I look forward to reading from you all.

Comment: Neither of my suggestions involved a `Service` or a `ContentProvider`.  I would say that you could effectively use a `Service` to do your background work if you wanted, but SQL has no purpose unless you are persisting data, and `ContentProvider` has no purpose unless you are sharing persisted data.  You mentioned neither of those things.  Both of my suggestions would allow you to retrieve and save in memory your data without it being directly attached to the UI.

Comment: Can you please direct me to a possible sample/link that may just enlighten me a bit. This would be greatly appreciated, of course.

Comment: Beyond the links I provided above, there is a sample in the ApiDemos that come with your SDK called FragmentRetainInstance or LoaderRetained and LoaderThrottle.  If you do not know how to access the ApiDemos, have a look here: http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Comment: Thanks so much, I have now found few approaches and have started grafting.;^))

Comment: I’ve been able to play around with the FragmentRetainInstance and it works ok and stopped crashing. The only problem I have with this now is that after loading the data it would not display the data straight-away on the first tab. On screen rotation the app does not crash at all but instead stays on the ProgressBar. I could see that it's recreating the tabs (of fragments – through respective onCreate) but will not display their contents after rotation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using fragments you should be using Loaders instead. Check the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

The fragment will find any previously created loaders and "reconnect", so you can get the results from it.

There are ways to "reconnect" AsyncTasks as well, but you're better off just using Loaders.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have the link to possible ways of reconnecting AsyncTasks?

Comment: Hmmm at the fragment level I'm not sure. But at the activity level you can use the `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`. This is now deprecated but allows you to save an arbitrary object (your AsyncTask) and get it back after the activity has been restarted. 

I'd suggest going with the Loader approach, as it is much more practical for Fragments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setRetainInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29), however as docs say this can only be used with fragments not in the back stack

Comment: The setRetainInstance will only be effective in this case if we use UI thread not when using parallel thread through AsyncTask

Comment: Async task lifetime is **independent** from Fragments/Activity. If your activity is killed your AsyncTask is not.